# sas insert blank raw into null dataset

Tags: sas, blank-line

I have a null data set such as

```
a b c d
```

and I want to insert a blank record as the first and the only record . I tried every think but not working.

Comment: What do you intend to do with a null dataset with a single blank row in it? Do you want a solution that works for non-null datasets as well?

Answer (score 2):

When you say you have a null dataset, do you mean it has 0 records, something like:

```
data have;
  a=.;
  b=.;
  stop;
run;
```

?  If so, then below will create a 1-record dataset which has the same variables, and all values missing:

```
data want;
  if 0 then set have;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

The `if 0 then set have;` statement is used to add all the variables in HAVE to the program data vector, so that they are output to WANT.  If you did `set have;` without the `if 0 then` part, the step would stop when the SET statement executed because SAS would read the end of file marker.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you soooo much!!

Comment: And probably worth mentioning that you _have_ to do it this way, and why `data want; set have; run;` won't work.

Comment: You don't need the `output;stop;` statements. SAS is smart enough to notice that you are no longer reading any new input and stop after it writes the first record.

Comment: True @Tom, but I treat the "DATA STEP stopped due to looping" NOTE as an error message, so I like the explicit STOP. which then requires explicit OUTPUT.

Comment: I consider the `stop` essential as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using dataset options. Use `OBS=0` on your source dataset to get the variable definitions and `OBS=1` and `DROP=_ALL_` on some other dataset like SASHELP.CLASS to get one observation, but no additional variables.

```
data want ;
  set have(obs=0) sashelp.class(obs=1 drop=_all_);
run;
```

If you need to define it from scratch then just run a data step that defines the variables, but does nothing else.  SAS will automatically write one record.

```
data want ;
  length a b 8;
run;
```

If you don't like the notes about uninitialized variables then add one or two ARRAY statements. One each for character and numeric variables.

```
array _num _numeric_;
array _char_ _character_;
```